# alterar dados JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json

tenho um formulário com vários campos quando, tenho uma função que ao submeter o formulário captura os campos:

```
$('.form').submit(function () {
                var dados = JSON.stringify(jQuery(this).serializeArray());
                alert(dados);
                return false;
            });
```

**os campos retornados em dados são:**

```
[{"name":"razao_social","value":"INTELIDER"},
{"name":"nome_fantasia","value":"INTELIDER LTDA"},
{"name":"cpf_cnpj","value":"10.999.558/0001-86"},
{"name":"rg_insc_estadual","value":"132456789"},
{"name":"login","value":"gleyson"},
{"name":"senha","value":"123456"},
{"name":"confirma_senha","value":"S"}]"
```

**porém preciso que fique assim:**

```
[
  {
      "razao_social": "INTELIDER",
      "nome_fantasia": "INTELIDER LTDA",
      "cpf_cnpj": "10999558000186",
      "rg_insc_estadual": "132456789",
      "usuario":       {
         "login": "gleyson",
         "senha": "123456",
         "ativo": "S"
      },
   }
]
```

Lembrando que preciso retirar um **confirma_senha** do primeiro código e acrescentar o campo **ativo** do segundo exemplo, para enviar esse Json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer a conversão para objeto:

```
$('.form').submit(function () {
      var dados = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
      var obj = {};
      $.each(dados, function (i,obj) {
          obj[obj.name] = obj.value;
      });

      obj.usuario = {
            login: obj.login,
            senha: obj.senha,
            ativo: obj.confirma_senha
      };

      var json = JSON.stringify([obj]);
      alert(json);
      return false;
 });
```

Caso prefira você pode usar o plugin serializeObject do jquery:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = Object.create(null),
        elementMapper = function(element) {
            element.name = $.camelCase(element.name);
            return element;
        },
        appendToResult = function(i, element) {
            var node = o[element.name];

            if ('undefined' != typeof node && node !== null) {
                o[element.name] = node.push ? node.push(element.value) : [node, element.value];
            } else {
                o[element.name] = element.value;
            }
        };

    $.each($.map(this.serializeArray(), elementMapper), appendToResult);
  }
```

> Modo de usar:

```
$('.form').submit(function () {
      var dados = jQuery(this).serializeObject();
      var json = JSON.stringify([dados]);
      alert(json);
      return false;
 });
```

Comment: o retorno ta vazio: [{"usuario":{}}], debuguei pelo chrome e percebi que ele não entra em **$.each(dados, function (i,obj) {
          obj[obj.name] = obj.value;
      });** , apesar da variavel ter conteudo, também não tem nenhum erro.

Comment: coloquei um alert dentro dessa função e vi que ele esta percorrendo o array dados normalmente, e vejo jogando os valores dentro do obj, porem não consigo le-los na **obj.usuario = {
                    login: obj.login,
                    senha: obj.senha,
                    ativo: obj.confirma_senha
                };**, eles vem vazio